# HTML5 & CSS ,internal css style not applying

Tags: css, html

I'm using an internal css  and whenever test it with any browser ,the style never applied to the tags.I have validated my code and it passed.Have no idea where did I go wrong.
If any can help me by viewing this page in his browser?Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Extend Your Knowledge - 3-1</title>

<style type="text/css">
<!--

body {font-family:"Garamond,Arial,Verdana; font-size:12pt;}

h1,h2 {color:red ; 
       font-variant:small-caps;}

.align-right {float:right;
              margin-left:15px;
              margin-right:15px;}

.align-left {float:left;
             margin-left:15px;
             margin-right:15px; }
a            {text-decoration:underline;
             color:red;}
a:hover      {background:red;
              color:white;}
              -->
              </style>

</head>
<body>

<section>
<article>
     <a id="top"></a>
     <h1>Isabel's Desserts</h1>
<p>We offer a variety of wonderful desserts at our cafe such as <a href="#eggnog">eggnog mousse</a> as well as <a href="#custard">decorative custards</a>.</p>

<a id="eggnog"></a>
<h2>Eggnog Mousse</h2>
<img class="align-left" src="mousse.jpg" width="560" height="420" alt="First dessert" />

<p>This first dessert is delicious. The mousse is light and fluffy and is always a customer favorite.</p>
<br style="clear-left" />
<br /> <br /><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<a href="#top">To top</a>

<a id="custard"></a>
<h2>Decorative Custards</h2>
<img class="align-right" src="custard.jpg" width="280" height="420" alt="Second dessert"  />
<p>This second dessert comes in several flavors, including chocolate, vanilla, and butterscotch. The custard is often selected as the dessert for special occasions.</p>
<br style="clear:right" />
<br/><br/>
<a href="#top">To top</a>
</article>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are commenting out your css

Comment: `<!-- -->` These are HTML comments, nothing in-between the opening and closing comment will be rendered.

Comment: Another suggestion I have would be to assign a class to your "To Top" link and then apply a `margin-top` to it instead of using dozens of breaks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typos:

```
body {font-family:"Garamond,Arial,Verdana; font-size:12pt;}
                                         ^-- missing "
```

You really should check your browser's debug console (e.g. shift-ctrl-j in Firefox) which would tell you about this. ANY errors in a css file will kill all of the rules after the error. Since you've got syntax errors with the html comments, and this `"`, basically you ENTIRE css ruleset is being ignored.

Comment: Oh ! U were right ! I removed the (") for the font family and bam it worked !What a stupid mistake Idid !I have been trying for three hours !haha Thank you so much :)))

Comment: The quote mark, if it is to be added, should be added after `Garamond`, not after `Verdana`, because otherwise the browser will be looking for a single typeface called `Garamond,Arial,Verdana` rather than three typefaces with their individual names.

Answer (score 2):

The Mistake is in the following line
body {font-family:"Garamond,Arial,Verdana; font-size:12pt;}

you missed " in the above line

Try this
body {font-family:"Garamond,Arial,Verdana"; font-size:12pt;}

Delete the Comments also